# Trying to publish gmail addon > public option is not available. (Filled out google's form, but no response)

Tags: google-apps-script, publish, google-apps-marketplace, gmail-addons

We've been working on converting our chrome plugin to gmail-apps. Took us awhile and now we are ready to release it. As we are going through publishing process, our option to set it as "Public" is grayed out:
[image]

I understand that gmail is limiting what gets published to gmail marketplace, however we are not even able to submit it for the review.

1. Are we doing something wrong? or we should be able to select it as public? I wonder if I'm missing a detail here.
2. I filled out the form, to ask for google's permissions, but haven't received a reply.

Thank you